# jQuery Mobile And a js counter executed twice

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a e-commerce site with a 20 min max basket time. I wrote a simple counter in JS to display the timeleft like this :

```
 function basketCounter() {
    var minutes = Math.floor(count / 60);
    var sec = count - minutes * 60;
    if (sec < 10) {
        sec = '0' + sec;
    }
    console.log("hello");
    $(".temps_restant").html("reste: " + minutes + " : " + sec );
    $("#tunnel_panier_temps").html("" + minutes);
    if (count == 0) {
        window.location = '{{serverRequestUri}}flush_panier/1/';
    }
    count--;
}
```

And in the body :

```
var count = {{panierTmp.lifetime - now}};
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("img.lazy").unveil();
    if (count > 0) {
        setInterval('basketCounter()', 1000);
    }
});
```

It works fine when I'm navigate on the site without ajax.
But when i'm trying to navigate trought ajax in JQM, the counter is re-executing each time and speeding, 2sec by 2sec, and if I go back twice it will be 3sec by 3 sec..

I can't find any solution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pageinit is wrong, it should be executed only once:

```
var count = {{panierTmp.lifetime - now}};
var interval=null;
$(document).bind('pageinit', function() {
    $("img.lazy").unveil();
    if (count > 0 && !interval) {
        interval=setInterval('basketCounter()', 1000);
    }
});
```

Without this check, every pageinit event will add another interval calling basketCounter.

You could also check data existence instead of setting a variable.

```
if(!$(document).hasData('basketCounter')){
    $(document).data('basketCounter',{{panierTmp.lifetime - now}});
}
```

Comment: Why my page init is wrong ?
Is there an event which won't be fire each time i go back and return on my view but only once?

Comment: I think i'm doing something wrong, and it's the main error of my page init, my ajax call is duplicating my page content

Comment: @user2695901 `Triggered on the page being initialized, after initialization occurs. We recommend binding to this event instead of DOM ready() because this will work regardless of whether the page is loaded directly or if the content is pulled into another page as part of the Ajax navigation system`. For short, it will always trigger when loading a page containing this event. checkout your page load, you should only retrieve the content not the whole page. but still, use the interval variable check to make sure the count is unique. You should use a date to check instead of a counter imo

Comment: In your sample code, my counter will never be fired cause intervall is always null

Comment: @user2695901 oops sry :p

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

1) try removing any hidden pages

```
<head>
    document.on('pagehide', function(e) {
       $(e.target).remove();
    });
</head>
```

2) Unbind and bind the page event.

```
$(document).off('pageinit').on('pageinit', ....
```

Comment: It looks like a dirty solution to me.. is that ok ?

Comment: Hey hi, no it is not a dirty solution. Normally JQM retain the first page loaded in the DOM (hidden), so if you go back later on, you may see the same page. Some apps do not want that behavior so it is common to apply that logic. I am talking about 1).

Comment: Ok ty for the explication, I already saw that JQM keep my previous page in the dom. I will use the first solution posted since its works but will keep in mind yours. Greetings